# Session lost after redirect

Tags: node.js, express, reactjs

I use `fetch()` to send a post request for logon, 
after server validation, I use `req.session.account = account[0];` to save the account information to the session and return a redirect URL,

But after the redirect, the account information in the session is lost, why is that?

Comment: Please share more details, especially about the errors occuring.

Comment: just lose the account information in session, I can not get account information via `req.session.account` after redirect.

Comment: Have a look at [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Your question is quite unspecific...

Comment: please share your block of code where you are stuck

Comment: tried making the question clear.

Answer (score 0):

If you would have some example code, that would help us track down the problem. My first idea would be to make sure `express-session` is properly configured:

```
var app = express();
var session = require('express-session');

app.use(session({
    secret: 'ibfiyegfiyegfe' // Secret is a required option.
}));
```

For futher configuration options, see the [express-session repository](https://github.com/expressjs/session).

EDIT: Based on the additional information, I'm guessing you have express-session configured to also use cookies for managing the sessions. What this means, is that for every HTTP request Express sends a response back that includes a cookie. jQuery based AJAX calls will ignore the response cookie however, which causes consecutive requests to Express to look as if you never logged in. To allow saving the cookie when performing AJAX requests with jQuery, use the `xhrFields` field to enable `withCredentials`:

```
$.ajax({
    url: "http://....",
    type: "POST",
    xhrFields: {
        withCredentials: true
    },
    data: {username: username, password: password},
    success: function(responseBody) {
        console.log("success!");
    },
    error: function(responseBody) {
        console.log("error!");
    }
});
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to everyone, I don't making the question clear.

I use the `fetch()` method send a request to logon.

```
fetch('/logon', {
        method: 'post',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            account: account,
            password: password
        })
    }).then(function(response){
        return response.json();
    }).then(function(json){
        if(json.success == 1){
            window.location.href = json.redirecturl;
        }else{
            indexDispatcher.dispatch({
                actionType: 'logonFaild',
                errorInfo: json.msg
            });
        }
    });
```

And the server's response is just simple JSON:

```
if (err) {
    consoloe.log(err);
} else {
    req.session.account  = account[0]; //save account to session
    var redirecturl = '/team/' + team[0].id; 
    console.log("account添加到session了");
    res.json({
        success: 1,
        redirecturl: redirecturl
    });
}
```

But when the client get the `redirecturl` and redirect, the `account` data is lost,so it will occur a `TypeError: Cannot read property 'id' of undefined`(id is saved in req.session.account).

But when I use `jquery $.ajax` relpace `fetch`, it works well. I don't know the reason.

Comment: See my response below, thanks for posting more information.

Answer (score -1):

I had the same experience like you hundreds of times which I finally found the problem. You don't need to worry if cookies enable or disable.

You just have to `re-declare` parts of your scripts (variables-the data which you want to display) in a `if else` condition.

Just `redeclare` the same thing using !isset and then else with the same variables mentioned twice in the `if else` condition, if you understand what i mean.

It will call back the same variables over and over. And make sure start `session` is above the page. no need to worry about headers or white lines, it has actually nothing to do with it.

I've tried it a million times. You don't need to bother using `ajax` etc. `PHP` can do almost everything. `cheerio`.